# How to stop deleting SMS from messaging app of android OS?

Tags: android, sms

Does anyone know the solution to this problem in android?

1. Can we get any event when a user delete SMS from Android messaging application.
2. If yes, then how will we intercept Android messaging application.

Please share your suggestions on these issues.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible but I guess you need to do something similar to what [AdamK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/268156/adamk) explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215696/context-menu-before-sending-sms/2217209#2217209)

Comment: Thanks for replying back, but i dont think we have same filter for deleting sms.

Let me put my req. more precisely.
-> When user deletes any SMS, App should be notified.
-> Basically i want to prevent users to delete messages in certain situations.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: @dhaiwat: I just checked the logs when you delete a thread and a sms and there is no intent sent. Also if you go through the sms app's manifest there is no intent-filter for that. So I guess it's impossible.

Comment: Any buddy have any different opinion??